# IFrame for IOS in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iframe

I'm new to IOS Js, i want to add two button to the below iFrame. Then get the click of those buttons. Any help will be appreciated.

```
                var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
                iframe.setAttribute("src", 'data:text/plain,');
                document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
                window.frames[0].window.alert('Please select the area multiplier');
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
```

If there is any other way to make an iFrame or if i can add a drop down in the iFrame and get the selected item of the drop down. Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have used a series of divs

```
 var mainCan=document.getElementById("cont");
 var mainCategoryDiv;
 mainCategoryDiv && mainCategoryDiv.parentNode.removeChild(mainCategoryDiv);
 mainCategoryDiv = document.createElement("div");
 mainVarS(mainCategoryDiv, "position", "absolute", "left", "0px", "top", "0px", "width", 645 + "px", "height", 700 + "px", "backgroundColor", "rgba(32,32,97,0.6)");
 mainCan.parentNode.appendChild(mainCategoryDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to positioning, general ui widgets have a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). 
W3 have a brilliant tutorial section on bootstrap, you'll be surprised what comes out of the box these days.

Why are you using an iframe?

Heres a few tips which can simplify your code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
             iframe.setAttribute("src", 'data:text/plain,');
             document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
```

If you're using jQuery you could:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe src="data:text/plain,"></iframe>');
$(document).appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.targetFunction().alert('please select the area multiplier');
```

Comment: Also check out this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: Still no solution mate :(

Comment: Please structure your question better, Ive tried to point you in some direction, but this question is not clearly defined at all.

Comment: Hey Rhys,

i got it figured and worked with other divs and frames.

Thanks for your help mate..

Comment: Please post the answer, so we can help others who find this page :)

Comment: Sure, Please find the answer below